# Non-isolated DC-DC converter for power supply and equipment at remote location (on top of a tower)

Tags: power-supply, grounding, surge-protection

I am designing a DC-DC converter system for powering equipment in remote locations (on top of a tower.) Each device needs 150 W of power.

I designed DC-DC converter both at ground-level power supply and for the remote equipment. Here is the logical connection:

[image]

This is how system will be deployed:

[image]

"REMOTE EQUIPMENT" to "POWER SUPPLY" has maximum distance of 100 m (or more if power cable somehow not routed efficiently.)

The DC-DC converter in "POWER SUPPLY" and "REMOTE EQUIPMENT" share the same ground.

Question:

1. Is a non-isolated (shared ground) topology like this is problematic for this use case? Should I use an isolated topology instead (flyback with transformer?)
2. How would a lightning strike (on top of the tower) affect remote equipment and ground-level power supply if this topology is used?
3. If a grounding cable at tower that connecting busbar to ground somehow disconnected, what risk exposed to remote equipment and ground-level power supply?
4. If a grounding cable connecting busbar to busbar somehow disconnected, what risk exposed to remote equipment and ground-level power supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a non-isolated (shared ground) topology like this is problematic
> for this use case? Should I use an isolated topology instead (flyback
> with transformer?)

Not necessarily, but any EMI that induces currents into the OV line or -48V line will make the DC to DC converter in remote equipment box susceptible to the EMI. The other problem from the looks of the diagram the 0V ground and the -48V are also in a loop which has the potential to generate very high currents in the event of a nearby lightning strike.

> How would a lightning strike (on top of the tower) affect remote
> equipment and ground-level power supply if this topology is used?

In the event of a lightning strike, the very large current (100's of A) would flow through the lightning cable, which would generate a very large magnetic field. This would couple into any conductor following the same path and generate a smaller current on each cable.

Any loops on cables would capture and magnetic energy and the loop would generate a current (orange loop current)

In addition the sudden change of electric field would generate a large voltage change on the remote equipment box (green capacitance)

[image]

The remote equipment box could see thousands of volts (should be shielded) and the terminals could also see transient events lasting [around 200us](https://www.industrial-electronics.com/DC_pwr_9.html). This voltage could be high (such as ±2kV)  could be common or differential (seen on one terminal such as the -48V or both -48V and 0V at the same time)

[image]
Source: (pg 560) [Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering. Author(s):. Henry W. Ott.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQO8u.png)

I don't see any suppression circuitry on the DC to DC converter. I suspect that a 2kV spike would be outside of its specs. I would consider using isolation. This would break the ground loop and using a transformer does two things:

1. supresses differential noise
2. Transformers can be mad to saturate to limit energy moving into your device, suppression diodes after the transformer can then be used to suppress any high voltages.

> If a grounding cable at tower that connecting busbar to ground somehow
> disconnected, what risk exposed to remote equipment and ground-level
> power supply?

No grounding cable would eliminate one of the ground loops, but lower the ability of the grounding system to keep the electronics at earth potential.

> If a grounding cable connecting busbar to busbar somehow disconnected,
> what risk exposed to remote equipment and ground-level power supply

The current from the -48V rail would be shunted to ground and the ground impedance would increase. Any potentials generated between grounds would be seen by the electronics.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. to clarify I want to further ask:
(1) Regarding to EMI, is shielded power cable (e.g. [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000543081612.html)) will not help prevent EMI that introduced along power cable path?
(2) If grounding cable and power cable mounted parallel as close as possible, and lightning cable mounted as far as posible, will induced current from lightning strike reduced? with 200 us transient I assume TVS diode are not enough for suppress transient and I need to add gas dischage tube, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, shielding will prevent *capacitive coupling* from electric fields, but it will not fully attenuate magnetic fields, especially very strong ones, magnetic fields go through all materials and are only attenuated. Yes, if the 0V line and -48V line are used with a twisted pair this will reduce the magnetic loop area, but there is still a loop from the ground line. It's hard to say how much suppression you will need, in AC mains large transients are known. MOV's and transformers are used to block large transients.

Comment: Yes, you'll need more than just a diode because you need to handle transients that can carry large amounts of energy, which could blow out a diode.

Comment: Thank you very much